# SQL Server Management Studio - Create database with files at specific location

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2008 R2 Express), how do I create a database with files at an arbitrary location, say "`K:\SQL_DATA`"? I have been able to create it at default location, detach it, move the files, attach it. But it sounds like a lot of unnecessary steps. I would like to use **GUI** if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily define both the **path** as well as the actual **file name** in the `Create New Database Wizard`:

[image]

Comment: Well, somehow I missed that bit. Thanks.

Comment: You also need to make sure the the SQL Server Service Account has the necessary permissions to access that location.

Comment: @SebastianMeine: yes, absolutely!

Comment: This isn't very obvious because the user must scroll the view panel to the right most times.

Comment: Note that you may need to add write permission to the database instance in order to have it write at that location; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/21663874/3873799#comment117383454_21665509